# Isometric Unity 3D Game. How to shot a projectile?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making an isometric 3D game. I made two joystick, one to move the player and the other one to shoot a projectile when the joystick is released. I made 3 attemps to achieve this result,but there's every time a problem. first try was with this :

```
clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(newpos);
```

but this need a rigidbody and a projectile can't be a rigidbody because it start from inside of the player.
Second try was this:

```
clone.transform.Translate(dir * (launchForce));
```

but this doesn't have a "speed" so it just move instantly to the position, not by moving, but translating 
and the same happens with the third attemp:

```
clone.transform.position=Vector3.MoveTowards(Player.transform.position,newpos,10f);
```

This is the best solution until now because it gives me the possibility to choose a max range between the start posititon and the newposition.
Here's the full code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class shoot : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
private Image bgImg;
private Image joystickImg;
private Vector3 inputVector;
public GameObject proiettile;
private Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
private Vector3 newpos;
public float launchForce;
public Rigidbody Player;
private GameObject clone;

private void Start()
{
    bgImg = GetComponent<Image>();
    joystickImg = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
}

public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
{
    Vector2 pos;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(bgImg.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {
        pos.x = (pos.x / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

        inputVector = new Vector3(pos.x * 2 +1, 0, pos.y * 2 - 1);
        inputVector = (inputVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? inputVector.normalized : inputVector;

        // Move joystickImg
        joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition =
            new Vector3(inputVector.x * bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3
                , inputVector.z * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 3));

    }
}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
{
    OnDrag(ped);
}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
{
    dir.x = Horizontal();
    dir.z = Vertical();
    newpos = dir * (launchForce);
    clone = Instantiate(proiettile, Player.transform.position, Player.transform.rotation);


    //third attempt
    //clone.transform.position=Vector3.MoveTowards(Player.transform.position,newpos,10f);
    //second attempt
    //clone.transform.Translate(dir * (launchForce));
    //first attempt
    //clone.velocity = transform.TransformDirection(newpos);


    // joystick come back to start position
    inputVector = Vector3.zero;
    joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;

    //temporary solution to replace the absence of a max range for projectile
    clone.timeoutDestructor = 5;
}

public float Horizontal()
{
    if (inputVector.x != 0)
        return inputVector.x;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}

public float Vertical()
{
    if (inputVector.z != 0)
        return inputVector.z;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would use rigidbody attempt. Just make sure it does not collide with player by setting collision layers/disabling collider for first fraction of second/spawning projectile outside of player.
Why?
Two main reasons:

Rigidbody will handle interpolation for you out of the box (without it movement may be glitchy)

Rigidbody will handle "between frame" collisions with CCD for you out of the box (without it your projectile may go trough walls, or even targets if it's fast enough)

And these two features will save you a lot of time later

One of attempts:
When I spawn projectile I check with SphereCast (or whatever shape it has) if it's colliding with something. If it is I change isTrigger to true and then in "OnTriggerExit" I change isTrigger to false again. If it is not colliding with anything on spawn I just set isTrigger to false at start and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, I Will try tomorrow, can you write me some code example about disabling collider? I actually Guess that the best choice Is to male It spawn in the position of the player + size of the player, but as I said, I Will try It tomorror. Thanks for your advices, can I ask you Just One more advice about how to hit another player?

Comment: No sry you got everything here:
When I spawn projectile I check with SphereCast (or whatever shape it has) if it's colliding with something. If it is I change isTrigger to true and then in "OnTriggerExit" I change isTrigger to false again. If it is not colliding with anything on spawn I just set isTrigger to false at start and that should do the trick.